# View object becoming nil abruptly - xcode

Tags: xcode, reference, ios6, retaincount

I have a View object becoming nil abruptly in my method.

I am not using ARC

no threading is involved

---

Whats happening is that 1st time i call that **1stmethod** method everything works fine and the reference to the livescoreSettings is retained.

Next when i call **2ndmethod** method also the livescoreSettings ref is retained but by the time the delegate method gets activated the reference of that variable is lost.. dont know why...

```
@interface XY {
    LiveScoreSettingsView * livescoreSettings; // initialisation in .h file inside    
}
@end

@implementation

// 1st method
- (void)1stmethod:(id) callingClass username:(NSString*)username {
    livescoreSettings=callingClass;   // retain count increases to 1 
    isLivescoresSettingsView = YES;

    //.... some code where the above livescoreSettings variables are not used ... //
}

// 2nd method  
- (void)2ndmethod:(id) callingClass username:(NSString*)username matchid:(NSString *)matchid  eventType:(NSString *) eventType  add:(NSString *) add {
    livescoreSettings=callingClass;
    isLivescoresSettingsView = YES;
    addEventToList = YES;

    //.... some code where the above livescoreSettings variables are not used ... //
}

// delegate method thats activated when the response comes 
- (BOOL)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender didReceiveIQ:(XMPPIQ *)iq {
   // the block where the data is sent to a particular view to reload table 
   else if(isLivescoresSettingsView== YES || addEventToList == YES) {
    isLivescoresSettingsView=NO;
    addEventToList = NO;

     //.... some code where the above livescoreSettings variables are not used ... //

    if(success)
        NSLog(@"No Errors with retain count = %d ", [livescoreSettings retainCount]); 
    else
        NSLog(@"Error Error Error!!!");

    [livescoreSettings.tableView reloadData];

   // when **2ndmethod** is called there's no memory reference to  livescoreSettings, tableView delegate methods are not called which is obvious. But not sure why the retain count is reducing abruptly.
    }
}

@end
```

Comment: Also is `livescoreSettings` an instance variable?

Comment: No ARC...    livescoreSettings is not an instance variable.. it is declared in .h file

Comment: no.. no threading involved

Comment: OK so if `lovescoreSettings` isn't an instance variable, where **is** it defined?  This is like 20 questions and it shouldn't have to be!

Comment: If you see the comment in the code i have put i have mentioned the same in it that its declared in the .h file @interface

Comment: edited it but ... -1 because the question didnt contain the relevant info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are not taking ownership of `livescoreSetting` that is being passed into `1stmethod` or `2ndmethod`.  If you are not using ARC then you will need to `retain` it in those methods and `release` it in your `dealloc` method (simply assigning the instance to `livescoreSetting` does **not** increase the retain count when using MRR).

Imagine if `1stmethod` is called in this way:

```
LivescoreSettingsView *view = [[LivescoreSettingsView alloc] init];
[whateverItsCalled 1stmethod:view;         // (1)
[view release];                            // (2)
```

Then `view` is being assigned to `whateverItsCalled.livescoreSetting` at (1), but the retain count is 1.  After (2) the retain count is 0, however `whateverItsCalled.livescoreSetting` is now a dangling pointer and I'm surprised you don't see messages like "message sent to deallocated object" rather than the errors you are seeing (I cannot see why it's being assigned to `nil` when ARC is not involved).

To solve the problem, you need to `synthesize` your setter/getter methods for the instance variable by adding a `@property` for it.  I prefer to name the instance variables using a leading underscore (`_`) to differentiate them from the setter/getter methods names; so:

.h file:

```
@interface WhateverItsCalled : NSObject
{
    LiveScoreSettingsView *_livescoreSetting;
}

@property (retain, nonatomic, readwrite) LiveScoreSettingsView *livescoreSetting;
```

.m file:

```
@implementation WhateverItsCalled
@synthesize livescoreSetting = _livescoreSetting;

- (void)dealloc
{
    self.livescoreSetting = nil;           // Release the object by assigning nil
    [super dealloc];
}

- (void)firstmethod:(id) callingClass username:(NSString*)username
{
    self.livescoreSettings = callingClass;   // Note the use of self!
    isLivescoresSettingsView = YES;
}

- (void)secondmethod:(id)callingClass username:(NSString*)username matchid:(NSString *) matchid  eventType:(NSString *) eventType  add:(NSString *) add

{
    self.livescoreSettings = callingClass;   // Note the use of self!
    isLivescoresSettingsView = YES;
    addEventToList = YES;
}
```

Comment: I totally agree BUT :D --- just to add info: You don't need either the variable or the @synthesize anymore -- just a property is enough (Xcode 4.5+)

Comment: @Daij-Djan Agreed; with the new features of Xcode/clang this isn't required.  Perhaps I'm old fashioned as I like to look at a class definition and see what instance variables it uses rather than having to work it out from looking at the `@property` section.  For me this wasn't an improvement from Apple; just an excuse to be lazy...

Comment: actually i tried this.. making it a property.. yet doesn't work... it looses its reference when the secondMethod is called..

Comment: @trojanfoe - Thank you. Your answer helped & resolve the issue